# Polynomial and its derivative have a common factor?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, divisibility

When is $gcd(p(x),p'(x))\ne 1$ where $p(x)$ is a polynomial?

That is when does the derivative of a polynomial and the polynomial has a common factor?

By when i mean some condition for the coefficients and degree of polynomial.

Obviously valid for $kx^n$.

(I came accross this when i had to determine in a problem that derivative of a rational function had to have a perfect square in the denominator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: working in $\mathbb C$, we have $$p(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n\left(x-\alpha_i\right)^{n_i}$$where the $\alpha_i$ are the distinct roots of $p(x)$ in $\mathbb C$.

- What is $p'(x)$?
- If $gcd(p(x), p'(x)) = 1$, what can you say about the roots of $p$?

Extra hint:

> What happens if $n_i > 1$ for some $i$

Comment: I couldnt get you.

Comment: Which bit don't you understand?

Comment: Well \(p'\) can be calculated but what do you mean by second point and what is the connection?

Comment: Have you calculated $p'$ yet? You may have to calculate it to see the connection.

Comment: yes, but $p'$ calculated but still not see anything

Comment: Yes now i see, thanks.

Comment: So, it must not have repeated roots.

Comment: If $gcd(p,p') = 1$ then it won't have repeated roots. So the answer to your question is that it *does* have repeated roots

Comment: Yes i meant same thanks.

Comment: I know this is a really old question, but how would you deal with this in a field that isn't algebraically closeD?

Comment: @whycantihavealongername In order to talk about $p(x)$, you need to assume that $x$ is an element of whichever field you are working over. The exact same argument works over the splitting field of $p(x)$ (at least assuming that $p(x)$ is separable). You definitely don't need algebraic closure.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer!